# Nginx 404 Not found on Linux Fedora

Tags: linux, nginx, fedora20

I'm trying to host my laravel project in Fedora 20 64 bits

I've install everything :

- My SQL : 15.1
- NGINX : 1.4.7
- PHP : 5.5.26
- and other small things as usall

My portal keep showing

```
404 Not found
```

---

```
server {

        listen   80;
        root /usr/share/nginx/my-site/public;


        index index.php index.html index.htm;

        location / {
                try_files $uri/ $uri /index.php?$query_string;
        }

        location ~ \.php?$ {

                try_files  $uri =404;
                fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
                fastcgi_index  index.php;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;


                fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
                fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;

                #Prevent version info leakage
                fastcgi_hide_header X-Powered-By;
                proxy_read_timeout 300;
                include fastcgi_params;
        }


}
```

---

Did I forget to set anything here in the Nginx config ?

---

**Folder Detail**

```
drw-r--r--.  12 root root  4096 Jan 21 17:13 my-site
```

---

**Owner of Web Server**

`ps aux|grep nginx|grep -v grep`

```
root      92177  0.0  0.2 118484  2140 ?        Ss   10:41   0:00 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx
nginx     92178  0.0  0.3 118868  3460 ?        S    10:41   0:00 nginx: worker process
```

---

Comment: One observation is your `$uri/ $uri` should be `$uri $uri/`. Not sure it breaks things though.

Comment: does the folder have read/write access by the webserver user? did you try inserting a simple `index.html` file? did it work?

Comment: @RichardSmith : I tried updating it with your suggestion. Same result !

Comment: @semm0 : How do I find out the webserver user ? I believe that folder I am trying to load via NGinx own by root user. Is it wrong ?

Comment: @semm0 : I updated my post.

Comment: ok. As it's owned by root user, it is not accessible by any other user with less rights than root user. You can try (in folder `my-public`): `chown www-data:www-data public/ -R` . This will recursively change the owner of folder public and all containing files to user and group www-data. Give it a try, it cannot get worse as root user is definitely wrong in this scenario.

Comment: Got this `chown: invalid user: ‘www-data:www-data’` hmm...

Comment: please open `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`with your favorite editor and check line1: `user              nginx;`. so in this case, *nginx* would be the username. please check.

Comment: Yeah I have `user  nginx;` ... Ohh man, should I change it to root ?

Comment: You're answering my question. Feel free to answer it.  I will ask a new question since my page now is showing `No input file specified. `

Comment: change it to nginx: `chown www-data:www-data public/ -R` and try again. put a simple *index.html* with something like "Hello world" in this directory.